# Pycharm Won't Display Shape Images

Tags: python, pycharm

Highly new to python and coding in general, but loving it so far. However, I'm trying to do a simple shape exercise and I just can't seem to get the new window to pop up to display it. I did a turtle race exercise that made a bunch of turtles run and that displayed fine. The code I'm trying to display is below (the necessary items for the import are copied and pasted from the course on a separate tab, if that helps).

EDIT - the code does run, but it exits without displaying the paper and shape.

```
from shapes import Paper, Triangle, Rectangle, Oval

paper = Paper()
rect1 = Rectangle()

rect1.set_width(200)
rect1.set_height(100)
rect1.set_colour("blue")

rect1.draw()
paper.display()
```

Comment: Follow the code in this page : https://www.futurelearn.com/info/courses/object-oriented-principles/0/steps/31483

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have you tried running your code directly from the command line? Does it have the same issue? Unfortunately since we don't have the code you're importing, this isn't a [MRE] and we can't do much more than speculate.

Comment: Is the code HMH1013 linked to the same as what you're using?

Comment: Hi HMH, that's actually the exact exercise I'm doing. The turtle one was just before that and everything seemed to work just fine.

Comment: Hi CrazyChucky - yup, that's the exact one. And also, thank you for putting the format right in the post!

Comment: Change your code ` rect1.set_colour("blue")` to  ` rect1.set_color("blue")`

Comment: Appreciate it HMH1013, but that didn't do it. I'm not sure if it's more of a software issue or something, rather than an issue with the code.

Comment: That's odd... Calling a nonexistent method should have thrown an error. (Also that module is not well-designed... Python doesn't need an army of setter and getter methods like that.)

Comment: That's what's driving me mad, it acts as if there's no issue, gives me nothing to fix. It's why I'm starting to think maybe it's a setting or a software issue on my end. But then the turtle exercise wouldn't have worked

Comment: Have you tried doing other things that should raise an exception, and seeing if they do?